# how awk redirection to a file, based on field value works

Tags: awk

curious to understand and learn how awk redirection to a file based on field value works.

Have noticed below command in one of the script which is creating files with 3rd field as names and entries only with their respective values, but unable to understand how it works

Also is it possible to create the output with only field 1 in output.

- Command in script

  ```
  awk '{print >> ( $3 ".txt")}' filename
  ```
- Input file

  ```
  sample_text1 text3 20190426
  sample_text2 text4 20190426
  text1 abc 20190425
  text2 def 20190425
  ```
- generated output's (20190426.txt and 20190425.txt)

  20190426.txt

  ```
  sample_text1 text3 20190426
  sample_text2 text4 20190426
  ```

  20190425.txt

  ```
  text1 abc 20190425
  text2 def 20190425
  ```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html

Comment: You can change `print` to `print $1`

Comment: i want to create  output file based on third fields but in output can we have only $1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer now. As the 3rd field holds the essential part of the target file name, the latter is contructed from it and then used for the redirection of the print statement, which by default prints $0, the entire input line

Comment: Additionally, it would _append_ to the file if it existed before, due to using `>>` rather than `>`.

Comment: @Kusalananda - thanks for mentioning